# How to redirect every url parameters to the root?

Tags: javascript, express, url, path, routes

I'm trying to create a route with express js. I want the parameter (idk if you call it a parameter or a path) in the url after the root (/) to be redirected to /en (yes it's not the root as mentionned in the title, but I had no other idea for the title). I want also an exception for the parameters /en and /fr because these will be the only two routes of my website (and here is my main problem).

Here is my attempt :

```
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
    response.redirect("/en");
});

app.get("/:lang", (request, response) => {
    if(!request.params.lang === "fr" || !request.params.lang === "en") {
        request.params.lang === "";
    }

    if(request.params.lang === "fr") {
        response.render("index.ejs", {
            // translate in french
        });
    } else if(request.params.lang === "en" || request.params.lang === "") {
        response.render("index.ejs", {
            // translate in english, default language
        });
      }
}
```

So I only managed to redirect the root to /en, but it remains me the problems explained right above.

Any thought to solve my problem ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: um what is the problem exactly one more time please?

Comment: @SolomonPByer I want the parameter of the url (anything it it) to be redirected to /en